# jquery datatable not pagiging except first page

Tags: datatable, datatables

[image]
I have a datatable with server-sider processising.
Data come from table expected but it doesnt page by datatable. I see in debug total record count 14 of the database aaData whic gonna display is 5,
so I expect there will be 3 page.. but only 1 page diplayed and 5 rows in the page.

here is my tabl html:

```
<table style="text-align: center" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="usersTable">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            User Name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Account
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Enable
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Remark
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

and datatable def:

```
var tableObject = $("#usersTable").dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "../../Controller/UserManagementControllercopy.php5",
        "aoColumns": [
         { "mDataProp": "0", "sWidth": "40%", "bSearchable": false },
         { "mDataProp": "1", "sWidth": "20%"},
         { "mDataProp": "3", "sWidth": "20%" },
         { "mDataProp": "2", "sWidth":"20%" }
         ],
         "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback){
         $.ajax({
         "dataType": "json",
         "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         "type": "GET",
         "url": sSource,
         "data": aoData,
         "success": function(result){
             fnCallback(result);
         },
             error: function (xhr, textStatus, error){
                 debugger
                 if (typeof console == "object") {
                     console.log(xhr.status + "," + xhr.responseText + "," + textStatus + "," + error);
                 }
             }});
         },

         "oLanguage": {
         "sLengthMenu": '<select>' +
         '<option value="5">5</option>' +
         '<option value="10">10</option>' +
         '<option value="20">20</option>' +
         '<option value="30">30</option>' +
         '<option value="40">40</option>' +
         '<option value="50">50</option>' +
         '</select> Show'
         },
        "fnDrawCallback": function(){
        },

        "aaSorting": [
            [1, 'asc']
        ],
        "aLengthMenu": [
            [5, 15, 20, -1],
            [5, 15, 20, "All"]             ],

        "iDisplayLength": 5
    });
```

and servercode:

```
$aColumns = array( 'USERNAME', 'ACCOUNT', 'REMARK', 'ENABLE');
            $sQuery = " SELECT USERNAME,ACCOUNT,REMARK,ENABLE FROM users LIMIT ".$_GET['iDisplayStart'].", ".$_GET['iDisplayLength'].";";
            $dbObject = Connection::getConnection();
            $request = $dbObject->dbh->prepare($sQuery);
            if ($request->execute())
            {
                $resultData["Data"] = $request->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $sQuery = "SELECT COUNT(USERNAME) FROM users";
                $request = $dbObject->dbh->prepare($sQuery);
                $request->execute();
                $iTotal = $request->fetchColumn(0);
                $output = array(
                    "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
                    "iTotalRecords" => intval($iTotal),
                    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => intval($_GET['iDisplayLength']),
                    "aaData" => array()
                );
                for ( $j=0 ; $j<count($resultData["Data"]) ; $j++ )
                {
                    $aRow = $resultData["Data"][$j];
                    $row = array();
                $output["Success"]=true;
                echo json_encode($output);
            }
```

and here how returned data from get request of datatable seem is:
(chrome developer console)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are returning the wrong value for iTotalDisplayRecords in the json array. It should be the Total records, after filtering (i.e. the total number of records after filtering has been applied - not just the number of records being returned in this result set)
see the [documentation](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side) and refer this
https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/512/clarification-of-itotalrecords-and-itotaldisplayrecords

Comment: @Vishan Hello, I changed the code in serverside for it like this: ...          "iTotalRecords" => intval($iTotal),
                    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => intval($iTotal),...
And I see it works perfect now. But I cant understand why it works now :)) why itotalrecords and itotaldisplayrecords must be same ? Or is there anything I miss again

Comment: @Mehmet You are missing the point again.  For your current code it will work as you are not using any filter. 
But, if you will use some filtering WHERE condition or Datatable Searchbox you wont will get the expected result again. 
See, itotalrecords is the count of total records that you have in database for the respective tables and itotaldisplayrecords is the count of records that you get after filtering(like if you will use search box).

Comment: Yes I figure it out. And now I wonder this; runing queries three times (select count(*) from table & select count(*) from table where ... ) for itotalrecorads and itotaldispalyrecords.  and (select column1, column2.. from table) for table content data. Doing this every get request each time move page in table. So it seems causes performance issue.. what is efficient way of achieve this.

Comment: there was an option to use sql_calc_found_rows. 
I prefer to use indexing and run 2 queries for getting results and count. see this link -
http://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/
for performance you need to optimize your queries i would say.

Comment: Hey bro maybe you want to check this out; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221368/jquery-datatable-deleterow-without-ajax-request
thank you